# Tables not joining as expected

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, 1 being a Quiz and the other being Questions.

Quiz Schema is like:

```
{
    "id":  ,
    "name": "",
    "description": ""
}
```

Questions Schema is like:

```
{
    "id": ,
    "name": "",
    "options": "",
    "correct_option": ,
    "quiz": ,
    "points": ,
}
```

Now, I have to join these two tables in such a way that I get following values:

```
{
    "name": "sample_quiz",
    "description": "sample text",
    "questions" :
    "id": ,
    "name": "",
    "options": "",
    "correct_option": ,
    "quiz": ,
    "points":
}
```

Here's the query I have made so far. However, it isn't producing the required result.

```
select 
    quiz.*, 
    questions.* 
from quiz 
inner join questions on questions.quiz = quiz.id 
where quiz.id = 10
```

Where am I going wrong?

Note: Quiz column in Questions table is a foreign key to ID from Quiz table.

Comment: Are you running MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Also: are you actually looking to produce a JSON result?

Comment: SQLite actually. I'm not looking for JSON result. I'll handle that later on.

Comment: OK. But how do you want to represent that nested data structure in a tabular result? Please show us your expected result as tabular text to clarify that.

Comment: Made the required changes. Check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks fine. If you are not getting the results that you expect, it is probably because you have columns that have the same name in both tables being joined. I would suggest using column aliases to avoid that:

```
select 
    quiz.id quiz_id,
    quiz.name quiz_name,
    quiz.description quiz_description,
    questions.name question_name,
    questions.options question_options,
    questions.correct_option question_correct_option,
    questions.points question_points
from quiz 
inner join questions on questions.quiz = quiz.id 
where quiz.id = 10
```